# Fastes way to transfer multiple (~ 2GB+ each) files from remote Linux server

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to constantly copy multiple large binary files from a remote Linux server. These files are all approximately 2 GB+ each, and there are usually 5-15 files I am interested in transferring at a time. Some times I just need 1 file, and some others I need 60+ files; but the "normal" transfer is 5-15 files.

I am currently just doing

```
scp me@server:/path/to/files/batch_num_*.lz4 ./
```

For my use case, is there a faster way of transferring these files to my local computer?

Comment: What is remote for you? Internet or Intranet? Can you administer the remote system or are you bound to ssh/sco?

Comment: `rsync` has the `-z` option for transferring data in compressed form, however, you already seem to have compressed data, meaning that the time gain in reduced data amount being transferred may be outweighed by the time loss due to the compression operations. Nevertheless, the `--partial` option of `rsync` would allow resuming aborted downloads, which is a good time saver considering the sizes you are dealing with.

Comment: @FelixJN, as you can see from the file extensions they are already compressed and additional compression will not be recommended.

Comment: I agree with @FelixJN to use rsync. Even if files are compressed I would use `-z` and `--partial`. rsync uses delta transfer algorithm, which will not be very useful in your case, but still is a smarter way to transfer than scp.

Comment: web server (nginx) could be a lot faster than scp but this needs to be tested

Comment: Are other solutions like FTD or udt an option or do you have to rely on SCP? With SSH and TCP/IP you have only so many options